# Google Guice with Junit and Mockito

Tags: java, jpa, junit, mockito, guice

## how can i inject EntityManager(jpa) with Mockito?

I wanna bind Mockito.spy(UserService.class) to guice injector.
but UserService.class has EntityManager for query execution.

When installing 'JunitServiceModule' in guice injector, EntityManager is not found.

**See below for error details**

```
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
  while locating com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService
  while locating javax.persistence.EntityManager
```

My code is below.
(The test code just made the error situation similar.)
(actually 'EntityManager' is located in UserRepository... It's just example!)
(@Transactional is belong to guice)

```java
public class UserServiceTest {
    @Inject
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Injector injector = new TestBuilder().init();
        injector.initMembers(this);
        Mockito.doReturn(10).when(userService).getEntityCount(UserEntity.class);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(10, userService.getEntityCount(UserEntity.class));
    }
}


public class TestBuilder {

    public TestBuilder() {
    }

    public Injector init() {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
            new TestDBInjectModule("test"),
            new JunitServiceModule()
        );
    }
}


public class TestDBInjectModule extends AbstractModule {
    private String unitName;

    public TestDBInjectModule(String unitName) {
        this.unitName = unitName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new JpaPersistModule(unitName));
        bind(JpaInitializer.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

    @Singleton
    private static class JpaInitializer {
        @Inject
        public JpaInitializer(final PersistService persistService) {
            persistService.start();
        }
    }
}

public class JunitServiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(UserService.class).toInstance(Mockito.spy(UserService.class));
    }
}


public class UserService {
  @Inject
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public UserService {} // <-- throw NullPointerException!!! since EntityManager

  @Transactional
  public void addUser(User user) {
    return entityManager.persist(user);
  }

  public Number getCount() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("select count(*) from user", Number.class).getSingleResult();
  }
}
```

Comment: Just move the `@Inject` in your `UserService` from a field onto the constructor (and use a constructor parameter), and you can eliminate nearly all of this.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- If use constructor, fail to execute code 'Mockito.spy(UserService.class)'. error: Please ensure it has 0-arg constructor which invokes cleanly.

Comment: You need to read the documentation on the tools you're using, particularly Mockito, instead of simply repeating code without understanding what it does. All you have to do is create a mock (e.g., `mock(EntityManager.class)`) and then pass it to the constructor normally (`new UserService(mockEm)`).